# Why are unsized types allowed in trait method declarations?

Tags: rust

Why are unsized types allowed in trait method declarations? For example, this code compiles:

```rust
trait Blah {
    fn blah(&self, input: [u8]) -> dyn Display;
}
```

But implementing `Blah` is impossible:

```rust
impl Blah for Foo {
    fn blah(&self, input: [u8]) -> dyn Display {
        "".to_string()
    }
} 
// error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn std::fmt::Display + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
// error[E0277]: the size for values of type `[u8]` cannot be known at compilation time
```

Giving `blah` a default implementation is also impossible:

```rust
trait Blah {
    fn blah(&self, input: dyn Display) -> dyn Display { "".to_string() }
}
// error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn std::fmt::Display + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
```

Nested unsized types are also not allowed. This inconsistency makes me think this is a compiler bug:

```rust
trait Blah {
    fn blah(&self, input: [str]) -> dyn Display;
}
// error[E0277]: the size for values of type `str` cannot be known at compilation time
```

I found a couple [old GitHub issues](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/19182) that claim this behavior is intentional, but I could not find a reason for it. Why is this intentional behavior? If implementing a trait of this nature is impossible, why doesn't the compiler catch it in the trait declaration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe there are two distinct concerns here: the unsized function parameter and the unsized return type.

### Unsized parameter types

Unsized function parameters are actually implemented and available in nightly Rust under [`feature(unsized_fn_params)`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/48055). It's likely this will be stabilized at some point, and then it will be possible to implement a trait like this one:

```
trait Crab {
    fn pinch(&self, data: str);
}
```

Which currently is un-implementable in stable Rust.

In fact, the standard library [uses](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/lib.rs.html#134) this feature to [implement `FnOnce()` for `Box<dyn FnOnce()>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/boxed.rs.html#1324-1330), which requires moving `*self` into the `call_once` method. Since `FnOnce` is (kind of) externally visible¹, and `std` is always allowed to use unstable features, there might not have been any way to implement `unsized_fn_params` (in nightly) without permitting trait functions to have them (in stable). However, that's only speculation.

See also [How to pass a boxed trait object by value in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65261399/3650362)

### Unsized return types

As the name hints, `unsized_fn_params` only affects parameters; unsized return values are still not allowed even under `unsized_locals` (the broader, more permissive, less complete feature). So the argument for allowing `-> dyn Display` is far less convincing, and there's a good case to be made that this is an actual bug, or at least deserving of a lint.

I believe the "intentional" part of this, in fact, only applies to parameter types, and including return types was an accident.

---

¹ The `Fn` traits are special because in stable they can only be used with `Fn(...)` syntax, not `Fn<Args>`, but are still valid in constraints and trait objects.